# Adding command line Installer help to MSI

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I've created an MSI that accepts several parameters in as values through the command line install.

Is there a way to include documentation in an MSI so when a user executes the MSI from the command line they can see information that I created on the custom parameters?

For example "Myproject.msi /?" would display the allowable parameters and a brief description.

Comment: Would be nice if Microsoft implemented this as a standard switch on an MSI file.  I guess for now I'll  wrap it in a batch :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but the *quickest* way might be to wrap it in a batch file that responded to the appropriate switches.

Comment: +1, and if you still want to distribute a single file only you might want to have a look at iexpress.exe which will create a self-extracting executable for you.

Comment: Or a bootstrapper/chainer (exe)

Answer (score 0):

Say that you allow users to pass the value MY_PARAM to your install, which makes the command line look like this:

msiexec /i yourapp.msi MY_PARAM=whatever

You could put a dialog in the UI sequence, which includes whatever documentation pertains to the use of the MY_PARAM property, and make the appearance of the dialog conditional on the property being set.

You can repeat that for however many parameters you're potentially interested in.  And you can dump your documentation into ScrollableText controls on those dialogs, which means it can be long if it needs to be, and you can do some formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I used to develop installers and have also worked as an application packager. Professional application packagers are used to hunting down this information in all kinds of places. Anything you do to make it easier is generally a huge plus, but not expected.

**Simply stating on a dialog where to find the info will do nicely**. Just don't make it a modal dialog such as a message box from a script custom action. Rather make it a regular dialog and ensure it obeys the setups UI level (in other words that it doesn't show up in semi-silent mode).

I would always be happiest if I could find a sample batch file with some nifty, meaningful combinations of values for the installer. In essence an "**annotated, sample command line**". In most cases it eliminates the need for much reading at all for an experienced packager. Make sure you create several sample command lines.

For the record: whenever I would get a new installation media I would generally:

- Search for: **Sample batch files**, **README.TXT**, **AdminGuide.PDF** or
  similar documents if available. I would also actively look for these on any download page for the setup.
- Do a test run of the MSI in interactive mode and actually read the dialogs. Any written info here would be very helpful. Generally it should state what  document to check.
- Open the MSI and look for
  UPPERCASE, **public properties** definable via command line and actually test what they would do. Looking up where the properties were used in the custom actions etc...

Most application packagers are quite capable on the command line issues. It is just a matter of making things quicker, and then a batch file is the preferred method. Listing all public properties in the Property table with some sensible values is also good.